# Disable auto-focus when program opens in Fedora KDE

Tags: linux, fedora, kde, user-interface

I use KDE on Fedora 29. I multi-task across multiple monitors. There are few things more frustrating than a program doing something that opens a new window and the OS changing the active focus to that window when I'm in the middle of typing in shell or something. How can you disable this behavior?

The common scenario for me is that I'll open Cisco ASDM and type my login credentials. The program then takes a moment to connect to the remote firewall (it's java and slow). When it's done connecting and getting its stuff together it closes the login window and opens a new window. Usually when I'm waiting for all of this to take place, I go about my work in another window and I'll be in the middle of typing or ssh'ing into a server and the active focus is switched to this new ASDM window instead of what I'm actually typing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a KDE setting called "Focus stealing prevention level".

You can find it under System Settings -> Window Management -> Window Behavior -> Focus.

[KDE Window Behavior Settings](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kwin/kcontrol/windowbehaviour/index.html#focus-focusstealing)

Comment: For anyone else looking at this. The exact location is System Settings -> Window Management -> Window Behavior -> Focus.